# How do I declare the Siesta Swift package as a dependency of another Swift package?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, siesta-swift

I'm trying to use the Swift package Siesta as a dependency for the package I'm building and reference it in my package code. I've identified how to import the package into my project in my `Package.swift` file which is simple enough:

```
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta", from: "1.5.1")
],
```

This causes the package to be copied into my package just fine. The problem I'm having is actually linking it up to my package so I can `import` it and reference it in code. I know I need to actually link it up to my target

I've read some other package files and because the package name for Siesta is like this

```
let package = Package(
    name: "Siesta",
```

And the products it declares are like this

```
products: [
    .library(name: "Siesta", targets: ["Siesta"]),
    .library(name: "SiestaUI", targets: ["SiestaUI"]),
    .library(name: "Siesta_Alamofire", targets: ["Siesta_Alamofire"]),
],
```

I should be able to just do this in my package file's target to use it

```
.target(
    name: "MyTarget",
    dependencies: [.product(name: "Siesta", package: "Siesta")]),
```

But when I try to build my package, I get an error:

/Users/blahblah/Desktop/MyPackage/Package.swift: unknown package 'Siesta' in dependencies of target 'MyTarget'

And not only that, all the targets for my single run scheme on my package go missing and I can't build again without discarding all my local version control changes. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

With Swift tools version 5.2 you have to provide a name argument when declaring your package dependency.

```swift
.package(name: "Siesta", url: "https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta", from: "1.5.1")
```

A working example of a Package.swift file:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyTarget"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // make sure to provide a `name` argument here
        .package(name: "Siesta", url: "https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta", from: "1.5.1")        
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyTarget",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Siesta", package: "Siesta")
            ]),
    ]
)
```

Source: https://forums.swift.org/t/package-names-in-swift-5-2/34886/6